# JSON Formatting - Multiple Files with Multiple Rows

Tags: python, json

I have multiple files which I need to format them to be one JSON file:

**Here is an example of a file which I have:**

{"t": "test", "title": "test", "content": "test"}

{"t": "test2", "title": "test2", "content": "test2"}

**What I need is to be like:**

[

{"t": "test", "title": "test", "content": "test"},

{"t": "test2", "title": "test2", "content": "test2"}

]

**What I have tried:**

I have the below python code:

```
import io
import os
import json

def wrap_files_in_dir(dirname):


data = {}

list_of_reviews = []


for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
    file_path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with io.open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as rfile:
            contents = rfile.read()
            list_of_reviews.append(contents)




with io.open('AppStoreReviews.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8' , errors='ignore') as wfile:
    data["reviews"] = list_of_reviews
    wfile.write(unicode(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
wrap_files_in_dir('/Users/Jack/PycharmProjects/MyProject')

print("Your Reviews marged and converted to JSON")
```

I know that I'm missing some code here which enter to each file in my directory.. or could it be something else? 
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I can't see the purpose of what you're trying to do?

Comment: It looks like a duct tape approach to fixing formatting. Why don't you parse the contents in and dump them back out with the `json` module? Arbitrarily adding curly braces doesn't necessarily generate valid json

Comment: Dupe: [How can I iterate over files in a given directory?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10377998)

Comment: I guess Jack wants to update the content of the files to add { in the beginning and } at the end. Practically, you do not want to do this kind of things blindly. As @roganjosh suggested, define what exactly you want to do. Can you specify the content of the files ? Python is awesome language and there are many ways to do things and by all means avoid what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are reading and writing in the same file so it is not very clear what you are trying to solve. Maybe create a new file and rename/move after you are done. Do format the data as others have suggested if you are trying to save it as a json string.

Comment: @roganjosh - I have many log files and I want to add the curly brackets to them to make the files as json files.

Comment: Did you read my comment? Without seeing the contents of the file, my guess is that it won't work. JSON is more than just encapsulating text in `{}`

Comment: @roganjosh, yes I understand it, but this is the only thing that I need is just to add the {} in the beginning and at the end of the log file text.

Comment: I Change the question so I believe that now you can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to literally add `{` and `}` surrounding every file in a directory, that's easy enough to do:

```
import io
import os

def wrap_files_in_dir(dirname):
    """For every file in the given directory, wrap its contents in brackets."""
    for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
        file_path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            with io.open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as rfile:
                contents = rfile.read()
            with io.open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as wfile:
                wfile.write(u'{\n')
                wfile.write(contents)
                wfile.write(u'}\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wrap_files_in_dir('/Path')
```

Note that this implementation makes several assumptions:

- The hardcoded path is a valid directory name
- Each file in the given directory is readable and writable by the current process
- The contents of each file in the given directory will fit in memory
- Each file in the given directory is a text file encoded as UTF-8
- Literally adding just `{` and `}` results in a correct output file
- The files in the given directory are not being concurrently modified by another process

Comment: What Python version do you use?
I use Python 2.7 and getting the next error:
TypeError: must be unicode, not str

Comment: Ah, if you're using Python 2.x then those need to be `unicode` constants: use `u'{\n'`. I'll edit to make that clear. (In Python 3.0 and newer, all strings are Unicode by default.)

Comment: Still getting some error:
line 17, in <module>
    wrap_files_in_dir("/Users/Jack/Desktop/Projects/temp")
  File "jsonformatting.py", line 10, in wrap_files_in_dir
    contents = rfile.read()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 302, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 23: invalid start byte

Comment: Well, that's because one of the assumptions I listed was invalid: the files in question are not all encoded as UTF-8. What encoding are they?

Comment: 0x87 is not a valid ASCII value -- ASCII only defines 127 characters, so 0x7F is the highest defined value. Your text is probably in some extension to ASCII. Code Page 1252 (`encoding='cp1252'`) is a reasonable guess if you're using a Latin-alphabet edition of Windows.

Comment: I Changed the above question so it will be more understandable.. do you think you can help me with that?

Comment: @JackRaif: I think I already did help you. I don't know what more I could do. I'm pretty certain that your files are not all encoded in UTF-8. Like I said, I suspect that you want Code Page 1252, although I can't know for sure without looking at the bytes of the files in question. Otherwise, the code you posted looks like it should work (assuming that the indentation on your computer is correct, since it's clearly incorrect in your question).